# Need Help with FindControl Function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm playing around with a form utilizing a repeater that I've been working on, and I'm currently trying to write an event handler that will get the value of certain controls inside of a repeater after the form containing the repeater has been submitted. I assumed that something similar to this would work if I wanted to retrieve the label from the first repeater item, then set the text of it to the text of another label:

```
protected void SubmitMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label MyLabel = (Label)MyRepeater.Items[0].FindControl("MessageID");
    MyLabel2.Text = MyLabel.Text;
}
```

Using this however, it seems that MyLabel.Text is empty. When testing if MyLabel is null after setting it, the result is false, so I'm trying to figure out any reason why MyLabel wouldn't have the same contents of that in the repeater item that I'm trying to set it to. MyLabel2 is already declared at the top of the class. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The text of the label in the .aspx file is not being databound inside the text attribute, but rather in the container of the label itself. I'll try the other method on Tuesday morning, as soon as I can get back inside my code, on Benjamin's suggestion.

Comment: Lush, can you post a snippet of your HTML/ASPX to show us how you're generating this.

Comment: actually if you can either post the URL or the raw HTML output I can tell a lot - I commonly use FireBug to see how the info was output to the screen. between that and quickwatch it is easy to find just about anything

Comment: The output HTML is just an empty span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes down to how you bind the data to your label on the repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">

<ItemTemplate>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CustomerName") %></asp:Label>

    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Country") %>></asp:Label>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Label1 the Text attribute is not set and the data <strike>is being bound on the client side to the control in the body of the Label.</strike> **gets written to the span tag after the Label has rendered to the page and is never directly tied to the Label Control. This only happens when you use in line script in the body of the Label, if it were just text, the body of the label always overwrites the Text Attribute value of a Label.**

For Label2 the Text attribute is being set <strike>so the binding is taking place on the server</strike> **forcing it to evaluate the inline script before it finishes rendering the Label** and is therefore accessible by your other controls.

Without actually seeing your repeater I am suspecting this is how your data is being bound.

Here is some test code to prove this case to you.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add("Customer");
            dt.Columns.Add("CustomerName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt.Columns.Add("Country", Type.GetType("System.String"));

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "Testcustomer1";
            dr[1] = "USA";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "Testcustomer2";
            dr[1] = "UK";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "Testcustomer3";
            dr[1] = "GERMANY";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "Testcustomer4";
            dr[1] = "FRANCE";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            //Bind the data to the Repeater
            Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
            Repeater1.DataMember = "Customer";
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }

    }

    protected void SubmitMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label MyLabel = (Label)Repeater1.Items[0].FindControl("Label1");
        Label MyLabel2 = (Label)Repeater1.Items[0].FindControl("Label2");
        //Empty String Text was never set server side
        Label3.Text = MyLabel.Text;
        //String is found because Text was set
        Label4.Text = MyLabel2.Text;
    }
```

plug it in and add a couple extra labels and you will see Label4 has the data you are looking for while Label3 is blank.

Comment: DataBinding would already have happened as it's after the Page_Load (or other) and before the next Page_load (or other)...?

Comment: The data is in the repeater and shows on the page but if the Label Text attribute is not set explicitly and they are placing the data in the body of the label then the label itself is never truly bound.

Labels are not meant to be set in such a way and in this instance you can see why.

Comment: But how does setting the data inside the label (not inside the text attribute) done client-side rather than server side; doesn't that imply that javascript or the like would have to be generated for the browser to do this? I'm not making assertions, as I don't have any of the code in front of me, but as I understand it, all inline script is processed server side.

Comment: That might be a good question because if you do some test cases you get wildly different results depending on the order of things you are trying to do.  I don't have the answer to why it works the way it does I just know what it does and how to form it to get the results you want even if they were not the results you would logically expect.  If you don't use inline script in the body of the label the body text overwrites the Text attribute text, but inline scripts throw those normal rules out the window.

Comment: I edited my initial answer to clear up the confusion of client-side rendering and instead used the order of events that I believe is happening to cause the inconsistencies.

Comment: Awesome, I can't wait to try this out. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but when the event is executed the repeater might not have yet repopulated. Since the call to the method is "ByVal" (VB speak) and not ByRef the value might get passed but the original object is not yet populated... Just a thought...

Comment: Late night and a few beers so don't judge me too hard... ;)